# Select rows based on max value or total in a second table

Tags: sqlite, join

I have two tables, *users* and *albums*. Each user can have zero or more albums.

Table *users*: id, ...

Table *albums*: id, userId, count...

Tables link: users.id <--> albums.userId.

The *albums.count* field contain the number of photos in the album.

I want to get:

1) The user with the most albums.

2) The user with the most photos, totalled in ALL their albums.

How I can get it?

Comment: have you tried something ? did you get errors ? please post some code ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one, you can use :

```
SELECT users.*
       COUNT(albums.id) as albumNumber
FROM users
INNER JOIN albums ON users.id = albums.userId
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY albumNumber DESC
LIMIT 0,1
```

And for the second one :

```
SELECT users.*
       SUM(albums.count) as photosNumber
FROM users
INNER JOIN albums ON users.id = albums.userId
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY photosNumber DESC
LIMIT 0,1
```